# How can I automatically order/reorder a has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a List record, and each List has many Stages, which will be created/deleted/moved around by the user. Currently, I have a 'position' column on the stages table that tracks the stage's position within a list, and I simply query them in ascending order. However, this has complications in circumstances where a stage is deleted or needs to be inserted into the middle of a list. Doing so would require updating the position of every stage after the inserted/deleted stage's position, which isn't very clean to me.

Here's a barebones example of what I have:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :stages
end

class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope { order(position: :asc) }
end
```

Then, if I wanted to do something like insert a stage into the middle of the list, I'd need to do:

```
def insert(stage, position)
    stage.position = position
    stages.where('position >= ?', position).each { |stage| stage.update(position: stage.position + 1) }
    stages << stage
end
```

Is there any way I can easily set up the sequence of these stages so that moving their order around or removing stages that doesn't require so many manual updates? Sort of like how counter_cache automatically updates counts

Thank you for any help

Comment: That's what I always did. Maybe there's an acts_as_something that will implement this, but I don't see how one can do this in another way.

Comment: [`acts_as_list`](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) implements precisely that.

Comment: oh wow that's perfect! thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's a gem called 'acts_as_list' made for this exact thing.
Thank you D-side!